# what is faster and why? where 1=1 or where 1 <= 1

Tags: sql

i would like to know which one of these will execute faster and why:

```
select column1 from table1 where 1=1
```

or

```
select column1 from table1 where 1<=1
```

would there be a difference in performance between oracle/sql server/mysql?

please also consider where instead of 1, we use some variable `x`

what would be faster assuming `x = 2`

```
select column1 from table1 where x=2
```

or

```
select column1 from table1 where x<=2
```

if you do have more answers, since it's closed, just add comments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure both `where` clauses would be optimized out entirely by a query planner with an ounce of sense.

Comment: You haven't even specified which database that the sql would run in, so there could be different answers as well.

Comment: @pst: Two different result sets?  They're just queries of the whole table.

Comment: Any reason you can't just write `select column1 from table1`?

Comment: @herrow Maybe you wanted an answer for `col = 1` versus `col <= 1`? Because what you wrote there doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: 2nd question i asked on this site and it is closed already. interesting group of people...PEACE

Comment: @herrow: Please do not be so hard on the SO community.  Certainly we/they -collectively- have been a bit quick in closing this question, but on the whole I hope you'll find SO to be helpful and friendly. I can't speak for who closed the question, but they may have done  so because this is such a blatant case of __premature optimization__: even if there was a minute difference in the query plan selected for each of the proposed idioms, this difference would be insignificant in comparison to the time it would take to shuttle _all_ the rows from the server to the client.

Comment: @herrow: I can't speak for the people who voted to close, but I would guess that they consider it *incomplete* for the reason stated by Orjan: when dealing about performance issues, one can't objectively say which is *faster* without context, i.e. the configuration (OS, hardware, and database engine) that you care about.  I would agree that it's still incomplete without those qualifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, those are nonsensical queries. But, in general, it's impossible to answer this sort of question definitively without comparing the query plans. A database system will evaluate queries differently depending on any number of factors including the indexes that are available and the size of the tables.

If you're using MySQL or PostgreSQL, you can get a query plan by adding EXPLAIN to the start of the query and running it in a terminal. See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) or [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/using-explain.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Any reasonable engine would spend essentially no time recognizing that those are both the same as TRUE.  Since there's no actual comparison to be done on a row-by-row basis there will be no effective difference in the execution speed of the query.

In any event, the *very* fastest way to write that is:

```
   select column1 from table1
```

which (again, in any reasonable engine) will by pass the query optimizer and generate a simple execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't know for sure without doing a benchmark, but I would say = is faster than <= because = is a simple equality operator where as <= is a range operator.  I'd be willing to bet that the difference is trivial though.

Comment: You would be wrong.  All number comparisons are the same on the CPU.

Comment: @dani nope simshaun is never wrong

Answer (score -1):

What Byron Whitlock says and, if there is a difference, obviously the first one is faster, because it needs a simpler comparison.

Comment: Why is it so obvious? Why is `=` simpler than `<=`? I would say that an order relation is easier to handle than an equivalence relation. But of course, just like you, I don't have any arguments, just my intuition.

Comment: Hehe okay you're right. Given there is no optimisation of the query, I would suggest the arguments are accepted as integers in both cases. I have no prove indeed, so my statement is a bit bolt, but I would assume they will both be tested in one processor cycle, making them equal as fast.